# Which regex to use to extract propoer information in stri_regex in R?

Tags: regex, r, stringi

I am trying to extract a name that comes after this word `gdac.broadinstitute.org_` in that character in R

```
element <- "<li><a href=\"gdac.broadinstitute.org_BRCA.miRseq_Preprocess.mage-tab.2015020400.0.0.tar.gz.md5\"> gdac.broadinstitute.org_BRCA.miRseq_Preprocess.mage-tab.2015020400.0.0.tar.gz.md5</a></li>"
```

I am using `stri_extract` from `stringi` package but it looks like I do not know much about regexes. I tried something like this:

```
stri_extract( element, 
                      regex  = "gdac.broadinstitute.org_")
```

Anyone could help?

Comment: Can you point out exactly what you want to extract from the string? "> gdac.broadinstitute.org_BRCA.miRseq_Preprocess.mage-tab.2015020400.0.0.tar.gz.md5</a></li>" - Do you want "BRCA" or everything after "gdac.broadinstitute.org_" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
stri_extract_first_regex( element, "(?<=gdac.broadinstitute.org_)[\\w\\.-]+")
```

In general, using regex `(?<=start)[set]+`, you can extract everything (everything what matches `set`) after expression `start`. More info about ICU Regular Expressions: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `stringi`, but it can be done using `gsub` easily. I could get where the name ends, so I assume name is everything following underscore to the `"`

```
gsub(".*gdac.broadinstitute.org_(.*)\".*", "\\1", element)
```